# Flutter Hot Restart and Hot Reload button greyed out

Tags: android-studio, flutter, visual-studio-code

I decided to learn flutter so i downloaded the plugin in Android studio. I followed the docs at Flutter's website in order to run the Hello World program. The project builds without errors and runs but it never gets past

```
Installing build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app.apk...
```

While at this point, the screen goes white and stays that way.

If I stop the process in Android studio and quit the app on my phone (Nokia 3.1plus, Android 9), then open the app manually on my phone, it loads up properly.

What I notice is that sometimes it stays stuck at `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...` while the screen stays white. At this point, it would have outputed

```
✓ Built build\app\outputs\flutter-apk\app-debug.apk.
```

I have tried with an emulator and it is the same. I have tried with VSCode and it is the same.

When I run "flutter run" in Command Line, It run the app on my phone without the white screen issue but I cannot use "r" or "R" for hot refresh or restart.

In VS Code debugger console, when I try to run r or R while the `Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...` is still running, it says

> global evaluation requires a thread to have been loaded

This is the result of flutter doctor

```
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.2, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.900], locale en-GB)
    • Flutter version 1.20.2 at C:\flutter
    • Framework revision bbfbf1770c (4 days ago), 2020-08-13 08:33:09 -0700
    • Engine revision 9d5b21729f
    • Dart version 2.9.1


[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.2)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\ADMIN\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-29, build-tools 29.0.2
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7361
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)

[√] VS Code, 64-bit edition (version 1.47.3)
    • VS Code at C:\Program Files\Microsoft VS Code
    • Flutter extension version 3.13.2

[√] Connected device (1 available)
    • Nokia 3 1 Plus (mobile) • ROOGALB8C2201609 • android-arm64 • Android 9 (API 28)

• No issues found!
```

What I have tried

flutter clean, invalidate cache and restart, changing my target sdk to 29, updating flutter and dart

I have tried most of the suggestions on the flutter github issues section.

Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: Did you try creating a new Flutter project ? From the `flutter create` command and from Android Studio ?

Comment: I did. I tried from command line and terminal in Android Studio and VScode. A friend is currently having a team viewer session. He has higlighted a problem I am currently working on. If it is resolved after this, I will answer the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After weeks of prowling the internet, I decided to do a full reset. I uninstalled Android Studio, deleted flutter completely from regular directory as well as all associated PATH and ENVIRONMENT variable, removed all traces of dart too. I also deleted all gradle, sdk and android files from C:/ directory
Basically started afresh. Worked like a charm.
Apparently something got broken

Answer (score 1):

Open the File menu and click Invalidate cache/ Restart. This solved for me !

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem however, I closed out all open projects and vscode, returned to open vscode with a prompt to install recommended vscode settings for Dart, Run the code without debugging and everything worked fine.

- Closed VsCode with project
- Opened VsCode again (system automatically prompted me to use VsCode recommended settings) to install VsCode recommended settings
- Run from the menu without debugging.

That solved the problem for me.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem and we fixed it by doing a simple step:
you can try this for windows with android studios:

1. go to file then
2. Project structure
3. select SDKs
4. and check JDK home path:
   this should be like this C:\Program Files\Microsoft\jdk-11.0.12.7-hotspot

This will rebuild your application and you will be able to run and hot reload you project again.